# Travel to Ireland with UK short visit tourist visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

As per the British consulate website, we can travel to Ireland with UK tourist visa. And my question is: we travel to London from US and back to US from Dublin, Ireland. Can we board flight from Dublin, Ireland to US without any restrictions using UK tourist visa?

I hold Indian passport, going to apply for UK visa from US.

Comment: What type of passports do you hold?

Comment: We can’t answer that for certain without knowing your citizenship

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: Hi, I hold Indian passport, going to apply for UK visa from US. Can I visit and board return flight from Dublin with UK tourist visa?

Answer (score 3):

The [British-Irish visa scheme](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme) only applies to visas that are issued through a joint visa application centre in China or India. It is therefore not available to you if you need to apply in the USA.

Your itinerary will therefore require you to apply for separate visas for the UK and Ireland.

---

As there's an open land border between Northern Ireland and the Republic of Ireland, it is *possible* that you can reach Dublin without being stopped by anyone even if you don't have a visa for Ireland. In that case you would almost certainly be *allowed* to leave the Republic by air. However, authorities will be able to deduce from airline passenger information that you must have entered Ireland without a visa, and this is likely to create problems in any future visa application to Ireland, the UK, or anywhere else they might share data with.

Comment: They can even stop you at the airport, my parter who doesn't even need a visa for Ireland was about to board a plane from Dublin and an Irish immigration official called her name and asked to see her passport.

Answer (score 1):

From the tone of your message you seem to be a US citizen. 
US citizens don’t need a visa for either the UK or Ireland. You are processed on arrival and as long as you can prove you’re able to support yourself and intend to return you will simply be granted a tourist leave stamp in your passport. This will be given to you when you enter Ireland through an official port of entry.

If you are not a US citizen and require a visa for entry to the UK you will also require a visa for entry to the Republic of Ireland. Immigration laws are harmonised between the two countries to preserve open borders between Northern Ireland and the Republic but they still operate separate regimes and don’t accept each other’s visas for entry. Check out citizensinformation.ie for info on your specific circumstance.

Comment: And **generally** don’t accept each others visas. There are exceptions with visas issued under the BIVS, though these are only for citizens of India and China at the moment, with further restrictions.

Comment: They're Indian, so probs best editing or deleting your answer